# Using PyGame to Load MP3 and Fade Out

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to incorporate sounds in our GoPigo and I am using Python. I installed PyGame and was trying to use `fadeout` but it seems not working. It doesn't generate an error but from what I am hearing when I run the code is that doesn't fade out. Any ideas

```py
def sound_bytes2():
    import pygame
    import time

    audio1 = "audio1.mp3"
    audio2 = "audio2.mp3"

    pygame.mixer.init()


    pygame.mixer.music.load(audio1)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(12.5)
    pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(10) 
    #pygame.mixer.music.stop()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(audio2)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(start=6.5)
    pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
    time.sleep(11.3)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit of the time parameter to [`pygame.mixer.music.fadeout()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) is milliseconds. 10 seconds are 10000 milliseconds:

```py
pygame.mixer.music.load(audio1)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

# play for 12.5 seconds
pygame.time.wait(12500)

# fade out for 10 seconds
pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(10000) 
pygame.time.wait(10000)
```